# killing a process by handle VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am opening an instance of internet explorer and then trying to close that instance.  the code I have only opens the website, it dose not close it.  What happens is it skips over the code that is supposed to close it and keeps opening up new tabs in internet explorer.  I want to close the first one before opening the second one.  this is the code I have so far:

```
Dim IE As Process = Process.Start("google.com") 'open the website
'close the website
Dim IEProcesses() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("IExplorer")
For Each Instance As Process In IEProcesses
    If Instance.Handle = IE.Handle Then
        Instance.Kill()
    End If
Next
MsgBox("The website has been closed")
```

After searching the forum I have found many questions like this but i cant seem to figure out why this dosnt work for me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Your Process.Start will start the default browser if you pass a string that can be recognized as a URL "http:\\google.com" The name of my processes is chrome. You might want to check if you are using the correct name. I didn't get a single match in Instance.Handle and handle of the process returned by Process.Start .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the Internet Explorer process is `iexplore` rather than `iexplorer` (notice the absence of ***r*** in the end of the first one I mentioned).

Thus your code should be:

```
Dim IEProcesses() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore")
```

However, something that has already been pointed out to you (in a now deleted answer) is that you don't need to iterate the processes like that. All you need to do is call `Kill()` on the variable you already have:

```
IE.Kill()
```

Finally, if you want/need to ensure that the URL is opened by IE *only* (and not Chrome or whatever the user has as his/her default browser) you should start it specifically, passing the URL as an argument:

```
Dim IE As Process = Process.Start("iexplore.exe", "google.com")
```

Comment: Visual Vincent, I have tried to use just IE.kill() however I get the following error
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

The code I am using is the following:

    Dim IE As New Process
                    IE = Process.Start("google.com")
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep(TextBox1.Text * 1000)
                    IE.Kill()

Comment: @Code123 : That means that either the process has already exited, or no new one was started and the main application handled it. What happens if you try my last code block?